# Default permalink structure causing Notice: Undefined property: WP_Query::$post

Tags: wp-query, permalinks

I use the wp for membership site. I use pages for the user log in, manage post, edit profile and etc.

When I apply the default permalink structure, I found that the debug mode show this notice on every pages (not post page).

```
Notice: Undefined property: WP_Query::$post in /var/www/example/wp-includes/query.php on line 2986 Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/example/wp-includes/query.php on line 3349
```

But when I use the post name for the permalink structure, this notice disappeared.

Though it seems is not a serious issue (is it?), but I'd to know what causing this warning?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found what causing this problem, turns out  it have to do with my **pre_get_post** hook. Because I using **is_page** to check the specific page, which is not appropriate.

Here is what I did

```
function check_page($wp_query){
   if($wp_query->is_page(array('1','2','3')) ){
           //do something here
     }
  return $wp_query;
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'check_page' );
```

So my solution to this is:

```
 function check_page($wp_query){
    $pageidarray = array('1','2','3');
   if($wp_query->is_page() && in_array($wp_query->query_vars['page_id'], $pageidarray) ){
           //do something here
     }
  return $wp_query;
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'check_page' );
```

Problem solved.